# converting a PyObject in python to multiple 2d arrays in android using Chaquopy

Tags: java, python, android, opencv, chaquopy

here is my python script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import copy
import imutils
def test(red,green,blue):
  mask = np.zeros((480,360,3),dtype=np.uint8)
  for i in range(0,360):
      for j in range(0,480):
           a=blue[i][j]
           b=green[i][j]
           c=red[i][j]
           mask[j,i]=(110,23,245);
  mask[0:480,0:360]=(110,23,245)
  cv2.rectangle(mask, (100,100), (200,200), (255, 255, 255), -1)
  b, g, r = cv2.split(mask)
  return b,g,r
```

now in mainactivity.java in android it is received by creating a pyObject ,but python function returns 3 ,2 dimensional arrays as tuple ,i need to convert this pyObject to 3 ,2dimensional java array

```
Python py=Python.getInstance();
PyObject pyf =py.getModule("hello");
PyObject obj=pyf.callAttr("test", red,green,blue);
int[][] data = pyf.callAttr("test", red,green,blue).toJava(int[][].class);
```

but as you can see if my python function returned 1 ,2d list i can convert into a java 2d array ,but what to do when it returns 3 , 2d array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add another dimension to the Java data type:

```
int[][][] data = pyf.callAttr("test", red,green,blue).toJava(int[][][].class);
```

Now `data[0]` is `b`, `data[1]` is `g`, and `data[2]` is `r`.

Comment: that works to but i actually wanted to know if i can store them in 3 separate 2d arrays? and how ?

Comment: `data[0]`, `data[1]` and `data[2]` are already 3 separate 2d arrays. That's how multi-dimensional arrays work in Java: they're arrays of arrays.